# Need to change the symbol of the operator in slickgrid toggle filter (angular-slickgrid)

Tags: ionic-framework, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

**Problem statement**

I need to change the symbol for the contains operator in the slick grid row filter feature in angular-slickgrid.

What I have tried is changing the operator in compoundOperatorList inside the column definition for all field types but it's throwing an error Type **'"*a"'** is not assignable to type 'OperatorType | OperatorString'.

Note: Where "*a*" is the symbol I'm trying to change for contains operator

[For reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWnvZ.png)

Comment: I believe I answered your question below and if I it helped then you should accept and/or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid and Slickgrid-Universal.

Most of the classes are extendables since they are TypeScript classes and I purposely use `protected` (instead of `private`) which makes everything extendable. However in the case of `operator`, it is a define list that you cannot change because that will break the library. The current list of `operator` is the following (ref [`operatorString.type.ts`](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/master/packages/common/src/enums/operatorString.type.ts))

```js
export type OperatorString = '' | '<>' | '!=' | '=' | '==' | '>' | '>=' | '<' | '<=' | '*' | 'a*' | '*z' | 'EQ' | 'GE' | 'GT' | 'NE' | 'LE' | 'LT' | 'IN' | 'NIN' | 'NOT_IN' | 'IN_CONTAINS' | 'NIN_CONTAINS' | 'NOT_IN_CONTAINS' | 'NOT_CONTAINS' | 'Not_Contains' | 'CONTAINS' | 'Contains' | 'EndsWith' | 'StartsWith' | 'RangeInclusive' | 'RangeExclusive' | 'IN_COLLECTION' | 'NOT_IN_COLLECTION';
```

You also made a mistake in your question, `a*` is equivalent to `StartsWith` **NOT** `Contains` (which is the default and is an empty string). If you try to change `a*` for something else, then the library will recognize it as an invalid `operator` and will not work.

So does that mean you can't do anything? The answer is No, you can create a Custom Filter that will behave the way you want it to. I know it's a lot of work but that is the only possibly solution since again `operator` is a defined list that you cannot change without breaking the library.

You can take a look at Angular-Slickgrid [Example 3](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/editor), the column with the title "Title, Custom Editor" uses both a Custom Editor and a Custom Filter.

I could maybe add a way to provide an alternate text in the future, that is instead of always using the `operator` as text shown in the compound dropdown list, but that's a feature request for a future version. As it is today you cannot change it unless you create your own Custom Filter

EDIT

in the next Angular-Slickgrid v6.5, that will land in a week or two, you will be able to change any of the operator texts or their description via the following grid option.

```js
this.gridOptions = {
  compoundOperatorAltTexts: {
    // where '=' is any of the `OperatorString` type shown above
    numeric: { '=': { operatorAlt: 'eq', descAlt: 'alternate numeric equal description' } },
    text: { '=': { operatorAlt: 'eq', descAlt: 'alternate text equal description' } }
  },
}
```

For reference, this is the Slickgrid-Universal [Pull Request](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/pull/1181) that will bring this new feature.

**Please Note** that the `operatorAlt` should not be more than 2 chars (or maybe 3) if you want them align properly. If you show more than 2-3 characters then you will have to adjust the CSS styling

For example, changing `=` to `eq` and providing a different description

[image]